# HTML page-redirect not working inside javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I've written a simple login page which sends an Ajax request to the back end. However I'm not able to redirect the page on successful login. Redirect works 1 in 15 times, not sure why this is happening. I've tried all the different possibilities of redirect like window.location.href, replace, reload and seeing the same behavior.

Any help here would be great.

```
function loginNow(form) {

        var uname, passwd;
        if ((uname = document.getElementById("username").value) === "")
             alert("Username cannot be empty!");

        if ((passwd = CryptoJS.SHA1(document.getElementById("password").value).toString()) === "")
            alert("Please provide a password!");

        uname = uname.toLowerCase();
        var xmlObj;
        // For all known browsers
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }

        if (xmlObj.overrideMimeType) {
            xmlObj.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        }
        xmlObj.open("GET","../jsp/authenticate.jsp?username="+uname+"&password="+passwd+"",true);
        xmlObj.send();

        xmlObj.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlObj.readyState == 4)
            {
                var newData = xmlObj.responseText;
                var authData = JSON.parse(newData);
                var auth = authData.auth;

                if (auth == 0) {
                    **window.location = "http://www.google.com";**
                } else {
                    alert ("Login failed");
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: add console.log before window.location and see if that line is reaching

Comment: Add console.log(auth); after your var auth = authData.auth; to see what the server sends back .. this could be a server side error.. Also why do you have ** (asterisks) around window.location ?

Comment: It reaches the line and auth is zero. The response from server is fine. The window.location line is executed but the page redirection does not work. It works once every 15 times. The asterisk was to highlight in bold

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was a simple change in the HTML script.
Add return function() in the html call. This is essential if you have callback functions in chrome.

```
 <button onclick="return loginNow(this.form);">Login</button>
```